# EditText.setError doesnt show Error text and only shows icon

Tags: android, validation, android-edittext

I have a simple validation in my app, here I am using four `EdtiText`.I am showing error when `EditTex`t loses focus but, the problem is on losing focus `EditText` only shows icon without error message. I have tried using `requestFocus()` method and can now see the error but the problem is.. now my form shows two cursors and even if the first field is not valid and showing errors, whatever I am typing goes into second `EdtiText`. Can anybody help me to fix this?
Thanks.

Here is my xml file -

```
<EditText
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:singleLine="true"
android:hint="first name"
android:id="@+id/edt_first_name"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="last name"
    android:id="@+id/edt_last_name"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/edt_first_name"/>
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="email"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:id="@+id/edt_email"
    android:layout_below="@+id/edt_last_name"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="password"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:id="@+id/edt_password"
    android:layout_below="@+id/edt_email"/>
```

and here is my main file where i am cheking **validations**.

```
firstname.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

            if (!hasFocus) {
                if (!Validate(firstname.getText().toString())) {

                } else {
                    firstname.setFocusable(true);
                    firstname.setError("not valid");
                }
            }else{
                firstname.setError(null);
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `TextInputLayout` for material `EditText` like :

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_application_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:minHeight="50dp"
            android:theme="@style/MyTextInputLayout"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.App.TextInputLayout">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/application_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/hint_application_name"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:inputType="text" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

and in your `Activity`

```
TextInputLayout til = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.input_application_name);
EditText applicationNameEdt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.application_name);
til.setErrorEnabled(true);
til.setError("You need to enter a name");
```