# EditText with DatePicker dialog not showing error text when date is not selected

Tags: android

i am working in a app that triggers local notification. for that i have coded to display a date in Edittext, such that when a user clicks on edit text, a date picker dialog opens.

In a case, if edittext is null, i have to show a error to the user and i have coded the below for that.

```
  btn_save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
       if (et_reminderDate.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
                        et_reminderDate.requestFocus();
                        et_reminderDate.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.reminder_selectDate));
                    } else if (et_reminderTime.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
                        et_reminderTime.requestFocus();
                        et_reminderTime.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.reminder_time));
                    } else if (et_dateDue.getText().toString().toString().length() != 0) {
                        et_dateDue.setError(null);
                        et_dateDue.clearFocus();
                    } else if (et_reminderDate.getText().toString().toString().length() != 0) {
                        et_reminderDate.setError(null);
                        et_reminderDate.clearFocus();
                    }else{
My project coding goes here!
}
                            }
```

But i am just getting the error icon. The error text is not shown. 
As of my assumption, i have validated for text in edittext. Is that i have to validate for date in Edittext to find whether the date is null?

Note: In the same code, i am getting error message for edittext with text values. For example, edittext where user can enter name. Only for 
Edittext with date picker i am not getting the error message!

Any help thanks!

Comment: coz edit text length is not equal to zero!

Comment: show full code please

Comment: I have pasted the code! @IntelliJ Amiya

Comment: @RamJay, please check my below answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show date picker on single click you must have set `android:focusable="true"` on `EditText` so either remove `android:focusable="true"` or make it `android:focusable="false"` and you are done.

Comment: Can you please share your xml? It is working code from my application. `edittext.setError()` will not work until unless it does not have focus. You can check documentation.

Comment: This is the answer! Thanks mate! I have to set focusable as true and after setting error text in code, have to set requestfocus!

Comment: Can you please tell me, how to show date picker dialog on first click? If i set focusable as true in edittext, its showing datepicker dialog in second click only

Answer (score 0):

Altough I cannot see the full code, I assume the problem is with `else if`statement.

I think they should be handled as seperate if statements.

Like this:

```
            if (et_reminderTime.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
                et_reminderTime.requestFocus();
                et_reminderTime.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.reminder_time));
            } 
            if(et_dateDue.getText().toString().length()!=0) {
                et_dateDue.requestFocus();
                et_dateDue.setError(null);
            }
```

Comment: Hi i have just pasted this piece of code from my project. So only else is there!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
if (et_reminderTime.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
     et_reminderTime.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.reminder_time));
     et_reminderTime.requestFocus();
} else if(et_dateDue.getText().toString().toString().length()!=0) {
     //remove the request focus for et_dateDue
     et_dateDue.setError(null);
}
```

Comment: Tried it. Its also not working. Now i have added some extra notes to my question. Can you please take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

So try this, i actually use TextInputLayout and TextInputEditText and never had problems

[EditText.setError doesnt show Error text and only shows icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34669970/edittext-seterror-doesnt-show-error-text-and-only-shows-icon)

Comment: Nope bro, i removed the piece of code and tested. Its not working :(